# Hyperledger Fabric 1.4: How to register to chaincode emitted events?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

In my chaincode I am emitting an event with the following command

```
ctx.stub.setEvent('sampleEvent', 'somedata');
```

I want to Listen to this event on the client application using the Node SDK.

I have the following questions,

- Do I need to use ChannelEventHub?
- If yes, from where do I import/require it?
- Which npm module do I need?
- I believe, the channelEventHub has the registerChaincodeEvent method,
  are there any examples on how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can strongly recommend this [page](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/index.html). There you will also find tutorials on how to implement it.

The package responsible for ChannelEventHub is the [fabric-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric-client).

```
npm install fabric-client
```

And using it in code:

```
var Fabric_Client = require('fabric-client');
```

Also you probably want to install fabric-ca-client for user registration/enrolling as well. As stated above you will find everything necessary on the page of the provided first link.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This was the same tutorial I was following and because it was not helpful I came here asking for help. But nonetheless. you cleared some of the doubts. Thank you. And this tutorial not very helpful.

Comment: In the tutorial they say to use const channel_event_hub = channel.newChannelEventHub('peer0.org1.example.com'); Without ever mentioning Where to import channel from. And then when I imported channel from the Fabric-Client module and tried to instantiate the ChannelEventHub using the given command I get the following error  TypeError: channel.newChannelEventHub is not a function.

Comment: After playing around with the module functions, I found that this is the right command to instantiate the ChannelEventHub -->  const channelEventHub = new ChannelEventHub('mychannel','peer0.org1.example.com'); ChannelEventHub was imported from the Fabric-Client module. Hope this helps anyone trying to register to chaincode events.